# Forge Viewer measure toolbar throws error

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I am using the Autodesk forge viewer with the newest version as suggested by the tutorial by loading the script: "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js". In the browser console, a error occurs coming from the measure toolbar extension which looks like follows:

[image]

Is this a known problem which will be fixed soon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for reporting it. I was able to reproduce it as well in Viewer version 7.70.0. The viewer team has been working on it. One of the reasons this was introduced in v7.70, is because the viewer stopped including some polyfills for IE11. It is intended to fix this in the coming v7.71 release.

Meanwhile, if the measure tool is used on your apps, you can set and use latest version 7.69.0. Sorry for the inconvenience.

https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.69.0/viewer3D.min.js

Regards

Comment: Hi @ToniMaccheroni. On 30th June, the Forge Viewer version 7.71.0 was released. I tested and the issue you had have been approached and resolved.
Regards